# How would I convert a wood burning fireplace to gas?

Tags: pipe, fireplace, natural-gas, retrofit

I have an insert that we use as a wood burning fireplace.  It would be fairly easy to run a natural gas line under the house to the location of the fireplace.  I would like to convert the wood burning to a gas fireplace.

Comment: It appears you were asking two separate questions, so I've removed the second question. If you have more questions, please feel free to ask them by clicking the Ask Question button.

Answer (score 1):

The plumbing is not that hard, but you'll need a new fireplace and a new stove.

See if it's legal to use flexible corrugated line where you live. It's covered in a yellow plastic jacket. Corrugated Stainless Steel Tubing (CSST).

It'll be MUCH easier to install, plus under a house where there is moisture it'll hold up better.